# BIRT Eclipse Reports

Tags: eclipse, templates, properties, report, birt

1. How can I put a background-color to the hole page of the report, not to a field or a row?
2. How can I mix 2 report templates, such as Grouped Listing and Dual Column Listing? I want to obtain the classes timetables of a school. Eg

   Class 1

   Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thurday Friday

   9-10
   10-11
   11-12
   12-13
   13-14

   Class 2
       Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thurday Friday

   9-10
   10-11
   11-12
   12-13
   13-14

Answer (score 1):

To add background color to whole page, go to master page -> click on the center area -> In Property Editor - Master Page -> Properties -> General -> Select the background color 
This will be applied to the whole page
Hope this works